# Node.js extremely inaccurate setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, settimeout, setinterval

Initially, I had a piece of code to perform certain operations periodically. Though I encountered weird performance and timing issues.

I isolated the main loop in its own script below

```
let sleepTime = 50 //milliseconds
var sleep = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
let state = {
    stopCalled: false,
    countLoops: 0,
    lastLoopTime: 0,
    loopDuration: 0,

    badLoops: [],
    badSleeps: []
}
let data = [1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 5, 4]
async function startLoop() {
    //necessary for first loopDuration
    state.lastLoopTime = Date.now() - 50

    while (true) {
        if (state.stopCalled) return
        state.countLoops++
        state.loopDuration = Date.now() - state.lastLoopTime
        state.lastLoopTime = Date.now()
        if (state.loopDuration > 100) {
            state.badLoops.push(state.loopDuration)
            console.log(`Bad loop duration: ${state.loopDuration}`)
        }

        //do some random work
        let rand = randomInteger(1, 7)
        for (let i = 0; i <data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] === rand) continue
            data[i] = randomInteger(1, 7)
        }

        let initialTime = Date.now()
        await sleep(sleepTime)
        let actualSleepDuration = Date.now() - initialTime

        //sleep duration should be <=50 milliseconds
        if (actualSleepDuration > 100) {
            state.badSleeps.push(actualSleepDuration)
            console.log(`Bad sleep duration: ${actualSleepDuration}`)
        }
    }
}

function randomInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.round((max - min) * Math.random()) + min
}
```

A summary of what the code does:
After startLoop is manually called, it should run the loop periodically every 50ms
I expected a +/-5ms inaccuracies which is ok.

However, the sleep function/ setTimeout function gets wildly inaccurate **upto 1 whole minute** especially after running for along time

[image]

I understand setTimeout, is more accurate if there is no blocking code, in this case, this is the only script running, which doesn't make sense to why there is so much lag.

**Is there a more accurate way to run a function?**

Done two tests From:
one from Electron 17.0.1
another from Node JS 17.5.0 REPL  with `.load file.js`

- OS: windows 10
- RAM: 16GB
- CPU usage: 1-10%

Comment: So what is it that you actually need to do here? Ensure a function executes as close to every N milliseconds? Why not use `setInterval`?

Comment: As an aside, I've now been running your script for a while, and `actualSleepDuration` is consistently about 50 to 56 milliseconds, as expected.

Comment: @AKX in some parts of my code yes, but i also had noticed, in some areas where I just needed the sleep function, setTimeout had the same issues (1-minute lag)

Comment: @AKX i have added image, kindly check.. the problem comes after a few hours. Had seen the lag after about 3hrs

Comment: That looks like a browser screenshot. Which version of Node.js are you running this with, in which OS, etc.?

Comment: @AKX updated  above

Comment: And have you been running _the above_ test script for about 3 hours each? Or have you been running something else, e.g. something that could cause a lot of memory use/fragmentation/... so garbage collection takes a long time? Have you looked at the performance profiler when you're starting to see this?

Comment: Nothing else is running, updated and restarted my computer to make sure.
I don't have much experience with the profiler, but I will try to see if there is anything unusual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of testing, found out that [chrome throttles background tabs/windows from Chrome 88](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/timer-throttling-in-chrome-88/)  ,which is great for websites on laptops to save on power

But really bad for electron apps (use Chromium engine), that should not be throttled.

To solve this you should change `backgroundThrottling` to **false**, which by default is ***true***

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {           
        backgroundThrottling: false,
    }
})
```

An excerpt from the [throttling doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11FhKHRcABGS4SWPFGwoL6g0ALMqrFKapCk5ZTKKupEk/view):

[image]

This affects both setInterval and setTimeout which all non-blocking javascript timers are built on